# How do I create a field where the customer can choose terms on a pick list in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, field, docusignapi, picklist

How do I create a terms pick list so customers are able to choose their terms when sending out a quote via the Docusign App Launcher?

Comment: It sounds like config question, "clicks not code". Try asking on dedicated salesforce.stackexchange.com site, more admins over there, greater chance of getting an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can save your picklist values and related project description master data in custom setting, then you can use trigger to auto populate description value based on picklist value selected.

Hope this will resolve your issue.